# Why don't "identical" index entries using math mode join?

Tags: indexing

I have a LaTeX document featuring these two index entries:

```
\index{Farbmodell!$\text{LCh}_{ab}$|main}
\index{Farbmodell!$\text{LCh}_{ab}$}
```

While being "identical" in my view, there are two distinct entries created in the `.ind` file:

```
  \item Farbmodell
    \subitem $\text  {LCh}_{ab}$\hspace{1em}\dotfill\hspace{1em}61
    \subitem $\text{LCh}_{ab}$\hspace{1em}\dotfill\hspace{1em}\main{39}
```

`|main` just indicates the main index entry, using `\newcommand{\main}[1]{\textbf{#1}}`. I don't understand where these extra spaces come from.

LaTeX packages being used are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
%
\makeindex
\begin{document}
```

On output, the relevant index part looks like this: [image: Part of the index output]

The first index was entered directly within a section that is part of a chapter, while the second index was entered inside a caption within a table within a section within the appendix. That caption (inside table after tabular) looked like this:

```
\caption[Pr... im $\text{LCh}_{ab}$ Farbmodell]%
{\label{\Lt{PRMG}}Pr... im $\text{LCh}_{ab}$ Farbmodell%
\index{Farbmodell!$\text{LCh}_{ab}$}
nach \cite[Table~10, S.~15]{ICC.1:2010}}
```

Comment: It's necessary to know *where* and *how* you define the index entries. I guess the one for page 61 is called in the argument to another macro. By the way, the `a4` package is obsolete and deprecated and likewise `german`: for the first use `geometry` with suitable parameters, for the latter `\usepackage[german]{babel}` (or `ngerman` if you use “neue Rechtschreibung”).

Comment: Trying to make a small complete example showed that the index is built correctly there, resulting in `\item Farbmodell
    \subitem $\text{LCh}_{ab}$\hspace{1em}\dotfill\hspace{1em}1, 
  \main{1}`.  So still: Where do the extra spaces come from?

Comment: Move `\index` *outside* `\caption`.

Comment: No these comments are not just "personal taste" as you see in your next question they were warning you that your document will have incorrect hyphenation for example.

Comment: My personal style is to add `\index` immediately after the ndex term. So instead of moving the `\index` past the caption, I copied it past the caption: Now I have one `\index` added correctly, and the other wrongly (as stated in the question). So where do these extra spaces come from?

Comment: @David Carlisle: Convincing arguments beat personal style ;-) I changed the input encoding (without actually understanding the implications).

Comment: the input encoding doesn't matter (so long as you specify the encoding you are using, it is surprising that is latin1 but if it is, it is) but using the ancient german package, and the a4 package is not likely to lead to a good outcome.

Comment: `\index` reads its argument verbatim which means that it behaves differently if used in the argument of _any_ other command. Normally the extra spaces don't matter but if you have the same  entry you need to always be in a command argument or always not.

Comment: So does this mean that `\text  {LCh}` and `\text{LCh}` are the same thing in TeX, but not for the `makeindex` program? If so that would sound like a bug in the `makeindex` program to me. I consider to postprocess the `.ind` output to "fix" these problems. I'd prefer that over moving the `\index` elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to fix the problem using `sed` (I had a `Makefile` anyway).

The `Makefile` is somewhat complex as it does some other clever things, but here is the core of the solution:

```
#...
echo "\# fixing $(MAIN).idx"; \
sed -E -e 's/(\\[^ ]+) +\{/\1{/' $(MAIN).idx > $(MAIN).idx~ && \
mv $(MAIN).idx~ $(MAIN).idx; \
echo "\# running makeindex on $(MAIN).idx"; \
$(Do.Makeindex) $(MAIN); \
#...
```

(Actually I feel LaTeX or `makeindex` should do that)